# Automated glossary references

Tags: glossaries

I'm writing a document where I have to use terms and abbreviations defined in a glossary a lot. I don't want to type `\gls{HPC}` each time I use the abbreviation `HPC`. It litters the code with more trash longer than the abbreviation I'm using and I might miss an occurrence of the abbreviation.

Is there a way to tell LaTeX to just always replace `HPC` with `\gls{HPC}` and `HPCs` with `\glspl{HPC}`? (To indicate the potential problematic that one term to be replaced can be a substring of a different one. It can be assumed, though, that no glossary element occurs as a substring of any term that is not a glossary element.)

I know that I can improve upon the situation by defining

```
\newcommany{\HPC}{\gls{HPC}}
\newcommany{\HPCs}{\gls{HPCs}}
```

but that still contains a backslash. Is this the best one can do without awfully much hacking?

Answer (score 1):

I don't recommend it, but you can use `\oldacronym` instead of `\newacronym`. Instead of:

```
\newacronym{HPC}{HPC}{H-whatever P-whatever C-whatever}
```

use:

```
\oldacronym{HPC}{H-whatever P-whatever C-whatever}{}
```

This creates the command `\HPC`. If the short form contains non-alphabetic content you need to use the optional argument:

```
\oldacronym[HiiPC]{H2PC}{H-whatever2 P-whatever C-whatever}{}
```

This creates the command `\HiiPC`.

The final argument is the key=value list that's supplied as the optional argument to `\newacronym`.

If you load the `xspace` package, `\xspace` is appended to the definition, but be careful of the various pitfalls. See [Table 13.2](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossaries-user.html#tab:xspace) in the `glossaries` user manual.

The reason this command is called `\oldacronym` is because it's designed to emulate the style of the `\newacronym` command provided by the obsolete `glossary` package (which the `glossaries` package replaced). In the long run this design caused too many problems, which is why it wasn't adopted in the replacement package.